# Time series group by day and kind

Tags: sql, sqlite, date, group-by, count

I create a table using the command below:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stats (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  session_kind INTEGER NOT NULL,
  ts TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
```

I insert some time series data using the command below:

```
INSERT INTO stats (session_kind) values (?1)
```

Some time after having executed several times the insert command, I have some time series data as below:

```
id    session_kind    ts
-----------------------------------------
1     0               2020-04-18 12:59:51  // day 1
2     1               2020-04-19 12:59:52  // day 2
3     0               2020-04-19 12:59:53
4     1               2020-04-19 12:59:54
5     0               2020-04-19 12:59:55
6     2               2020-04-19 12:59:56
7     2               2020-04-19 12:59:57
8     2               2020-04-19 12:59:58
9     2               2020-04-19 12:59:59
10    0               2020-04-20 12:59:51  // day 3
11    1               2020-04-20 12:59:52
12    0               2020-04-20 12:59:53
13    1               2020-04-20 12:59:54
14    0               2020-04-20 12:59:55
15    2               2020-04-20 12:59:56
16    2               2020-04-20 12:59:57
17    2               2020-04-20 12:59:58
18    2               2020-04-21 12:59:59  // day 4
```

What I would like to have a command that groups my data by date from the most recent day to the least and the number of each `session_kind` like below (I don't want to give any parameter to this command):

```
0    1    2    ts
-------------------------
0    0    1    2020-04-21  // day 4
3    2    3    2020-04-20  // day 3
2    2    4    2020-04-19  // day 2
1    0    0    2020-04-18  // day 1
```

How can I group my data as above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do conditional aggregation:

```
select
    sum(session_kind= 0) session_kind_0,
    sum(session_kind= 1) session_kind_1,
    sum(session_kind= 2) session_kind_2,
    date(ts) ts_day
from mytable
group by date(ts)
order by ts_day desc
```

If you want something dynamic, then it might be simpler to put the results in rows rather than columns:

```
select date(ts) ts_day, session_kind, count(*) cnt
from mytable
group by date(ts), session_kind
order by ts_day desc, session_kind
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Is it really necessary to explicitly request for each `session_kind` or can it be handled iteratively (automatically)? What I mean is that, if at some point, `session_kind` increases to 3, 4 or more, then I need to modify the SQL query for each new added `session_kind`.

Comment: I guess this is not the perfect solution because is not a generic solution. In his example, he showed only 3 kind of sessions. But, what if would he had 100 session_kinds? Does he must make 100 `sum()`?

Comment: @MichelGuimarães: yes, if you want to handle more `session_kind`s then you need to expand the `select` clause; that is because a SQL query returns a *fixed* set of columns (so this cannot be dynamic - unless you use *dynamic SQL*, which really is a different beast). I added another query to my answer, that puts the results in rows rather than columns: this would be 100% dynamic.

Comment: It says: "no such column: datets_day"

Comment: @sanchop22: sorry, typo. Fixed.

Comment: Ok, the second query works too after your fix. But the result is not really like I asked in my question (last table). Is there any way to convert it to what I need? If not, your first query seems more appropriate in my use case even though the second is more dynamic.

Comment: @sanchop22: no, these are the two available options here. You can choose the one that suits you best...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you just want to sum the values:

```
select date(timestamp),
       sum(case when session_kind = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_1,
       sum(case when session_kind = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_2,
       sum(case when session_kind = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_3
from t
group by date(timestamp);
```

You can also simplify this:

```
select date(timestamp),
       sum( session_kind = 1 ) as cnt_1,
       sum( session_kind = 2 ) as cnt_2,
       sum( session_kind = 3 ) as cnt_3
from t
group by date(timestamp);
```